# Overflow error with Select Case in For loop

Tags: vba, excel

I am a CAD engineer with a relativly small knowledge of VBA, but today I decided to modify a 5 year old program and came across this problem:

I have a combobox that can display items from 2 different sheets, depending on which one of two radio boxes is selected.
This works with Cases. Honestly, I have no idea how cases really work, so I don't know how the combobox knows which case to take, but it works, so I'm not changing it.

Now, currently, the code is like this:

which means if I add a new row into the table, I have to copy those case select things

```
Private Sub ComboBox5_Change()                        'Auswahl Rohr

    Select Case ComboBox5.Value
        Case Tabelle6.Cells(4, 3)                     'Welle in Rohr

            LängRo = Tabelle6.Cells(4, 6)
            OnCenRo = Tabelle6.Cells(4, 7)
            OffCeRo = Tabelle6.Cells(4, 8)
            MinRRo = Tabelle6.Cells(4, 9)

        Case Tabelle13.Cells(4, 3)                    'ROHR IN ROHR

            LängRo = Tabelle13.Cells(4, 6)
            OnCenRo = Tabelle13.Cells(4, 7)
            OffCeRo = Tabelle13.Cells(4, 8)
            MinRRo = Tabelle13.Cells(4, 9)

        Case Tabelle13.Cells(5, 3)                    'ROHR IN ROHR

            LängRo = Tabelle13.Cells(5, 6)
            OnCenRo = Tabelle13.Cells(5, 7)
            OffCeRo = Tabelle13.Cells(5, 8)
            MinRRo = Tabelle13.Cells(5, 9)

    End Select

End Sub
```

I tried to fix this with something like this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox5_Change()                        'Auswahl Rohr

    Dim for1 As Long
    Dim for2 As Long
    For for2 = 3 To 7
        If Tabelle6.Cells(for2, 3) = "" Then
            GoTo fert
        Else
            Select Case ComboBox5.Value
                Case Tabelle6.Cells(for2, 3)          'Welle in Rohr

                    LängRo = Tabelle6.Cells(for2, 6)
                    OnCenRo = Tabelle6.Cells(for2, 7)
                    OffCeRo = Tabelle6.Cells(for2, 8)
                    MinRRo = Tabelle6.Cells(for2, 9)

            End Select
        End If
    Next

    For for1 = 3 To 7
        If Tabelle10.Cells(for1, 3) = "" Then
            GoTo fert
        Else
            Select Case ComboBox5.Value
                Case Tabelle10.Cells(for1, 3)         'ROHR IN ROHR

                    LängWe = Tabelle10.Cells(for1, 6)
                    OnCenWe = Tabelle10.Cells(for1, 7)
                    OffCeWe = Tabelle10.Cells(for1, 8)
                    MinRWe = Tabelle10.Cells(for1, 9)

            End Select
        End If
    Next

fert:

End Sub
```

But now I get an overflow error when I press a button that uses var `LängRO`, and I don't really know why

Comment: You don't need to separate the case statements, the case is what separates them.  What line do you get the error at?  Overflow is when normally when you are trying to put to much or the wrong data in a variable.

Comment: Hey MatthewD I think I'll just go with the code of Tim, it simplifies the problem and since it's not my code I think it can take ages till I find the "correct" mistake in the code which causes the overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Private Sub ComboBox5_Change() 'Auswahl Rohr

    Dim v, arrRows, c

    v = ComboBox5.Value

    arrRows = Array(Tabelle6.Cells(4, 3), _
                    Tabelle13.Cells(4, 3), _
                    Tabelle13.Cells(5, 3))

    For Each c In arrRows

        If c.Value = v Then
            'Found a match - assign from that row...
            With c.EntireRow
                LängRo = .Cells(6)
                OnCenRo = .Cells(7)
                OffCeRo = .Cells(8)
                MinRRo = .Cells(9)
            End With
            Exit For  'stop looping
        End If

    Next c

End Sub
```

I'm not sure I followed exactly what your layout is though...

Comment: Hey Tim
thanks a lot, this simplifies the problem since I only have to put in one new line per new Item, thanks a lot!
Cheers